# PHP decode GB2312

Tags: php, character-encoding, decode, gb2312

I'm working on an IMAP email script and I have some lines coded in [GB2312](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312) (which I assume is Chinese encoding), looks like this `=?GB2312?B?foobarbazetc`

How can I start working with this string?  I checked `mb_list_encodings()` and this one is not listed.

Comment: ... You tried decoding GB2312 with UTF-8? Why didn't you try GB2312?

Comment: Well, yeah :/ `gb2312_decode()` but there isn't that function available.  Honestly, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) ?

Comment: @ajreal - Thanks am testing now.

Comment: And now your HTTP headers are screwed up. Your UTF-8 output is being interpreted by the browser as CP1252.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the base64-decoded data, then use mbstring or iconv. If you have the raw header, then mbstring.

```
<?php
$t = "\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3\n";
echo iconv('GB2312', 'UTF-8', $t);
echo mb_convert_encoding($t, 'UTF-8', 'GB2312');

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo mb_decode_mimeheader("=?gb2312?b?xOO6ww==?=");
?>
```

Comment: +1 That looks like it'll set me on the right track, thanks.  At least I have something to work with now!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Ignacio solved the meat of the problem with `mb_decode_mimeheader()` but for future reference these links are also helpful:

- http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet
- http://www.herongyang.com/PHP-Chinese/PHP-UTF-8-Chinese-String-Literals.html

The specific header string I was working with:

```
$subject = "=?GB2312?B?tPC4tDogUXVvdGF0aW9uIFBJSSBwcm9kdWN0cyA=?= =?GB2312?B?Rk9CIFNoYW5naGFpIG9yIE5pbmdibyBwb3J0?="
```

This required a page header of

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and PHP

```
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
echo mb_decode_mimeheader($subject)."<br />";
```

to output

```
主题: Quotation PII products FOB Shanghai or Ningbo port
```

Comment: That is what i am looking for.