# Concerning UTF-8 email addresses

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8

If I'm parsing an inbound email via php, and the address (through php) looks something like this:

```
=?UTF-8?B?5rWL6K+V5Zyw5Z2A?= <æµè¯å°å@server.tld>
```

And it's supposed to actually look something like this:

```
测试地址 <测试地址@server.tld>
```

Any idea how I could quickly convert from one to the other? Might be staring me right in the face, but regardless, not quite seeing it at the moment.

Regarding where this is occurring. Basically, assuming an arbitrary email is sent to a catch-all handled via a php script, the php script, on execution, reads the `to` header of this email:

```
$a = imap_open({inbox}FOO,[username],[password]);
$x = [mail index];
$headers = imap_header($a,$x);
$data = $headers->toaddress;
```

`$data` is what I'm concerned with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:--

see this url-

[PHP decode GB2312](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559649/php-decode-gb2312-updated)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode-headers.php

A better way to convert would be to use iconv, see http://www.php.net/iconv -- example:

```
<?php
$myUnicodeString = "Åäö";
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $myUnicodeString);
?>
```

Above would echo out the given variable in ISO-8859-1 encoding, you may replace it with whatever you prefer.

**another solution**

```
<?php
$headers_string = <<<EOF
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UHLDvGZ1bmcgUHLDvGZ1bmc=?=
To: example@example.com
Date: Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 +0000
Message-Id: <example@example.com>
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by localhost
    with SMTP id example for <example@example.com>;
    Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)
    (envelope-from example-return-0000-example=example.com@example.com)
Received: (qmail 0 invoked by uid 65534); 1 Thu 2003 00:00:00 +0000

EOF;

$headers =  iconv_mime_decode_headers($headers_string, 0, "ISO-8859-1");
print_r($headers);
?>
```

Comment: i have improve my answer please take a look and added another solution. see the Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UHLDvGZ1bmcgUHLDvGZ1bmc=?=

Comment: Testing it out as we speak! So far, so good. Sorry, I'm a little slower than the rest of you, lol. I'll reply again to confirm results in a minute or two. ^.^

Comment: Testing this solution out, I'm actually not entirely sure if it's working or not. I think I might be doing something wrong on my end, perhaps.

To confirm: The example supplied (Subject) in the solution is returning "PrÃ¼fung PrÃ¼fung" for me - I assume this is correct?

I replaced your example with my $data, to see if it'd return expected results, but it returned an empty variable instead of an array(). I'm not sure if maybe this means my copy of php is manging the data, or something else..?

Directly base64_decoding()'ing my $data returns "æµ‹è¯•åœ°å€". Not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: I have mention one more url in my answer. I am sure about it it is prefect answer according to your question.

Comment: ^ Above comment regarding secondary solution. First solution output seems to be identical to input - I don't notice any changes. :-/

Seems rather tricky. Solution looked good, and I'm hopeful for it, because I honestly don't know any solutions myself, but I think I might still be doing something wrong maybe.

Edit: Checking URL now. Posted this reply before I saw your follow-up comment.

Comment: see above the url I am sure about it it is prefect answer according to your question

Comment: Had additional unrelated complications that slowed things down a bit, but URL suggested seems to solve the issue. Thanks for the help, Abid. :)